# Targeting a pattern and if not found targeting a smaller and smaller subset

Tags: java, regex

I am interested in finding 7 words in a string.
These should appear **in order** separated by space.

Assuming that `String regex` has a string with the 7 words, I was interested if a match did not occur to reduce to 6,5,4 etc words.

A first regex I thought was:
`\\b(?:word1(\\s+)word2(\\s+)word3(\\s+)word4(\\s+)word5(\\s+)word6(\\s+)word7)\\b`

1. The above would occur by using a `StringBuffer` and after
   `splitting` the variable `regex` by space, I would construct the
   regular expression by `append`.
2. If I got **no** match I would loop again contructing the expression up
   to `word6` etc and further reducing to `word5` etc until I hit a match.

I am not sure I really like this approach.Can I improve it or do it in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the greedy (default) will do what you want

```
\\b(?:word1(?:(\\s+)word2(?:(\\s+)(?:word3(\\s+)(?:word4(\\s+)(?:word5(\\s+)(?:word6(?:(\\s+)word7)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)\\b
```

this will first attempt to match everything and then leave off `word7` then leave off `word6` ...

Comment: +1.This seems to work!I noticed though that if I omit the `?` at the closing parentheses then it does not work.I see that you treat the next words as logical units by `(?:)` but I don't full understand the regex.E.g. why the closing `?)` makes the difference.Could you please elaborate?

Comment: the closing `)?` make the entire preceding group (down to the matching `(`) optional

Comment: What would be the best way to build this string?Using a `StringBuffer`?Is there some better/standard way to dynamically build it?

Comment: If `word7` is by itself this regex does not find it.Why?

Answer (score 0):

you can combine words and space, and then you can specify your count limit, like it is 1-7 in your case. this could be an alternate solution

Comment: I didn't get what you said.Could you please elaborate?